# Remove pre-populated content from bootstrap modal form

Tags: jquery, arrays, object, bootstrap-modal, reset

I'm creating divs out of each object from the 'myData' array.
Also, I've a bootstrap modal which has a form to add an external object.
This external object will in turn get added to my array 'myData' and display it in the same format as mentioned above.

My problem is, on successful creation of external object, I should be able to -

1. Close the Modal on click of the 'save' button and successful creation of external object.
2. Whenever, I click on 'Add external object' button, the form in the modal should not have any pre-poulated content.

I tried to do this by using reset method, but it doesn't seem to work.
Could you please help me fix it?
Here's my complete code -

```js
var myData = [{
  company: "ABC",
  url: "www.abc.com",
  type: "internal"
}, {
  company: "CDE",
  url: "www.cde.com",
  type: "internal"
}, {
  company: "DEF",
  url: "www.def.com",
  toolName: "reportTool",
  toolURL: "http://www.toolURL.com",
  type: "internal"
}, {
  company: "EFG",
  url: "www.efg.com",
  type: "internal"
}, {
  company: "FGH",
  url: "www.fgh.com",
  type: "internal"
}];

$('#createData').click(function() {
  createDisplay();
});

function createDisplay() {
  $('.container').empty();
  myData.forEach(function(obj) {
  $('.container').append(
    $('<div>').addClass('box').append(
    $('<label>').text('Company Website: '),
      $('<a>').addClass('compUrl').attr('href', obj.url).text(obj.company),
    )
  )
  });
}

var objIndex;
$(document).ready(function(){



var $toolName = $('#newToolName');
var $toolURL = $('#newToolUrl');
var $toolInputs = $($toolName).add($toolURL);

  $toolInputs.on('change', function(e) {

  var toolName = $toolName.val();
  var toolURL = $toolURL.val();

  $toolInputs.prop('required', toolName || toolURL);

  });


  $('#createForm').submit(function(e){
  var toolName = $toolName.val()
  var toolURL = $toolURL.val()

  var toolFilled = !!toolName && !!toolURL;
  var toolUnfilled = !toolName && !toolURL;

  if (toolFilled || toolUnfilled) {
    createData(objIndex);
    return false;
  }
  return false;
  });
});

function createData() {
  companyName = $('#companyName').val();
  companyUrl = $('#companyUrl').val();
  toolName = $('#newToolName').val();
  toolURL = $('#newToolUrl').val();
  var extObj = {
    company: companyName,
    url: companyUrl,
    toolName: toolName,
    toolURL: toolURL,
    type: 'external'
  }
  myData.push(extObj);
  createDisplay();
  alert('Data created successfully!');
  //$('#createForm').reset();
}
```

```css
.box {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: skyblue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">

</div>

<button id="createData" class="btn btn-info">Create divs</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#extData">Add external object</button>
<!-- Modal -->

<div class="modal fade" id="extData" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="update-data" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <!-- Modal Header -->
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
      </button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Update Data</h4>
    </div>
    <form id="createForm">
    <!-- Modal Body -->
      <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="companyName">Company Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="companyName" placeholder="Company Name" required />
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="companyUrl">Website</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="url" class="form-control" id="companyUrl" placeholder="Company URL" required />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="newToolName">Tool Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="newToolName" />
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="newToolUrl">Tool URL</label>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="url" class="form-control" id="newToolUrl" />
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal Footer -->
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code to the `createData` function, to close the modal when the data has been created:

```
$('#extData').modal('hide');
```

[Read more here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-methods)

After that, reset the form like this:

```
$('#createForm')[0].reset();
```

According to the [w3schools documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_reset.asp) this needs to be done on a formObject, you tried it on a jQuery object.